# Blank page with centered writing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, titles

I am wanting to create a page with the words "Research Plan" in the center. I currently have the following code

```
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Research Plan}
\vspace*{\fill}% * is needed here
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Research Plan}
\vfill
\newpage
```

However the words "Research Plan" don't seem to be perfectly centered, they seem a bit too low. In an ideal I would have the text slightly above center but I am happy to try different ideas and see what is best.

Comment: As long as the text is only a few words, you can use the structure `\centerline{...}`.  Everything else you have looks okay.  A more "LaTeXy" construction is to place the text (and the font spec) between `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{0.25\textheight}
\begin{center}
\bfseries\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont \color{Tomato}Fiddle-dee-dee!
\end{center}
\clearpage
\lipsum[46]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks quite close to what I am wanting, how would I change the font size of this please? Also is there a way to get the text about 1/3 of the way down the page instead of slap bang in the middle? Thanks!

Comment: Which font size would you like to have?

Comment: About 60ish would be great

Comment: Do you mean 60 pt?

Comment: Yeah about 60 would be great, and then how would I get the text to be about 1/3 down the page, I am sorry for being a pain. I am quite new to LaTeX so thanks for the help!!

Comment: I've posted a code for that. The value of `\vspace*{...}`was found by trial and error, but you can adjust it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s `\AtPageCenter` or `\AtTextCenter` to position content at the centre of the page or text block:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\clearpage

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\makebox[0pt]{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Research Plan}}
  }%
}
\mbox{}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Research Plan}% Set something on the page

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

`\mbox{}` just sets a blank element on the page so it can be shipped out when you issue `\clearpage` (or `\newpage`) and also establish the appropriate marker for the contents entry. During page ship-out, `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*` places the content in the `F`ore`G`round of the page (just for that page as a result of `*`). The use of `\makebox[0pt]` ensures that the element remains horizontally centred, while `\raisebox{-.5\height}` ensures vertical centering.